# Copy of View or Draw same view in customView

Tags: java, android, android-layout, layout, view

- **I have 2 views.**

1. Will hold all my display data.
2. Will just observe the first view and display it.

Both view in the same activity. Like the below picture.

> 1st view has list data So it is changeable.

[image]

Any help will appreciate.

Thank you so much for helping.

Comment: Have 2 views of type 1 . You can wrap custom view inside a View Group and add the First View and then Custom View . Or something like that whichever fits .

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you @ADM . I want to display my 1st view exactly the same in my 2nd view. And when 1st view has data change of refreshed then 2nd view also got refresh because of the copy view.

Comment: Thats what i said you have to have 2 views u can not add same view twice or make copy of . have 2 views and handle the data change yourself .

Comment: Okay, @ADM Thanks.